# Seed method doesn't seed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

My seed method doesn't show any error, but it certainly doesn't seed anything after I run update-database from PMC. My problem is very specific, because of the overall structure of the database and usage of Identity. This is how Seed method looks so far:

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Users.Any())
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {

                FirstName = "Prvi",
                LastName = "Doktor",
                DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1977, 4, 3),
                EmploymentStatus = EmploymentStatus.Employed,
                PhoneNumber = "062/062-062",
                Email = "prvi@gmail.ocami",
                Address = "Kulovica 9",
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                EmailConfirmed = true,

            };
            userManager.Create(user, "P@ssw0rd");
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

My ApplicationDbContext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public DbSet<Dentist> Dentists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}
```

My models extend from ApplicationUser, which in turn extends from IdentityUser

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IModificationHistory
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)] //DataType is very powerfull Data Annotation, which can affect our view if we use EF, so I will try to accomplish as much as possible with that
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }


    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public EmploymentStatus? EmploymentStatus { get; set; } //This value is nullable

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }


    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here

        return userIdentity;
    }


}
```

Dentist:

```
[Table("Dentist")]
public class Dentist : ApplicationUser
{

    public string Place { get; set; }


    //Relations
    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
    public virtual Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
}
```

Patient:

```
[Table("Patient")]
public class Patient : ApplicationUser
{
    //Relations
    public virtual Dentist Dentist { get; set; }

    public virtual MedicalHistory MedicalHistory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to know, why it doesn't give any result and how should I look at this relationship that I made, or is there any other more logical relationship that could be made.

Comment: What does "but it certainly doesn't seed anything" mean? How do you measure that?

Comment: The Seed method will only run with the Update-Database command. (In the case you didn't create custom database initializers)

Comment: @ThomasWeller I check the database and there is no any data there, is there some other way you would recommend.

Comment: @NicolasZawada I edited the question (After I run update-database), sorry for not being more specific

Comment: If you want to debug the Seed method, you can follow these steps: Open another instance of Visual Studio, attach the debugger to the other Visual Studio, set a breakpoint and run Update-Database. This might help or give us some more information

Comment: Maybe databases are just not my primary topic, but you patients go ino a patient table, dentist go into a dentist table but where does an ApplicationUser go?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Since ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser the table is created automatically, because of IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, which is the same as writing public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

I typically use this approach:

1. Create an user in my system with the password I want from the register screen (or use the passwordhaser class, link below)
2. Find the user in db
3. Update `Seed` method with those values.

This way I'm not using any dependencies in the `Seed` method because that method will run on every migration and it may take a little while to complete.

The `Seed` method should use `AddOrUpdate` method:

```
protected override void Seed(BookService.Models.BookServiceContext context)
{
    context.Users.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
    new ApplicationUser () { Id = 1, FirstName = "FirstName", LastName="LastName", PasswordHash="<hash from dbase>" }
    );       
}
```

To generate the hash for the password you can also use the [PasswordHasher.HashPassword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher.hashpassword(v=vs.108).aspx) method.

This way EF knows when to add or update the values you provide in `Seed` method.

The `if (!context.Users.Any())` will only work on a new db when there are no records in that table.